# closing password form c#

Tags: c#, forms

How can I close the password form when my new form opens?

```
public partial class Password : Form
{
    private string password;
    public Password()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pass_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        password = "1234";
    }

    private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (passtextBox.Text == password)
        {
            list form = new list();
            form.Show();

        }
       else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password. Try Again!!");
        }
    }
}
```

When I use `this.close();` my new form and password form both close.
What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your `PasswordForm` is the main form for you which you passsed inside `Application.Run` method.

So when the main form closes application will exit.

I'd suggest you to just hide the form instead of closing it.

```
list form = new list();
form.Show();
this.Hide();
```

Comment: or you can call form.ShowDialog() and after that this.Close() because ShowDialog() will hang the execution.

Comment: @lauCosma Am not certain about that. I suspect that it will close the app still if `Close()` behaves synchronously. And it is not a good idea to close the MainForm before the App terminates

Answer (score 2):

You can use MDI form as the parent form. 
When a new form is created and that new form(which is a child form of the MDI form) is opened over the MDI or any parent form, then you can search for all the opened child form. If any child form is found open, then close that child form. In this way you can manage form opening and closing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show new form and close first form if password is correct, don't you?
Try this:

```
 Form secondform = new form();
 Secondform.show();
 Form1 firstform = new form1();
 Firstform.hide();
```

Comment: no i tried this and didnt work the password form still remain under the new one

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it myself

public partial class Password : Form
    {
        private string password;
        public Password()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void pass_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        password = "1234";
    }

    private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (passtextBox.Text == password)
        {
         // list form = new list();
         //form.Show();
             //list secondform = new list();
              //secondform.Show();
              //Password firstform = new Password();
            // firstform.Hide();
           this.Hide();
            list sistema = new list();
            sistema.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();


        }
       else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password. Try Again!!");
        }
    }




}
```

}

Comment: Hi Melody, I have a project in Arak and am looking for a html programmer. Could u email me please: msmhasani@yahoo.com. There is no way to send message in this site, so I commented here.